# Angled bottom border - full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I'd like to know how to create a div 100% width and say 300px wide where the bottom border is slightly angled across the full width of the box.

[image]

It can be done in either CSS or javascript but it needs to be responsive. I've seen examples of using borders but if I'm honest I don't fully understand using borders for super whizzy shapes.

Comment: An excellent resource for your perusal : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ & http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-border-shape/ They can be a bit tricky, but once you figure it out it's very simple!

Comment: Thanks - I saw your first link but was confused by it! I've been doing this for a while but to me borders just go round the edge !

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this :

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

We want to specify that we want to use the border as the main drawing feature.

We want the bottom left border to be transparent.

Then if we apply a reasonable height to it, we see it gets close to your image..

```
.box {
    border-right: 300px solid red;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    height:100px;

}
```

This then is a drawing of purely borders, stretched and sized so much they look solid.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs5emvd1/)

Making it responsive is a little more tricky as borders are not supported with percentage values.

You will always have a maximux border size set in a fixed value.

In our case we will use 300 px as previously, so our `.box` class becomes like so :

```
.box {
    border-right: 300px solid red;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    right:0px;
    float:right;
}
```

We are going to pull right, so that the solid looking image will actually float left.

We will then add a wrapper which will have an overflow of hidden, so even though the `border-image` will not change size, the overflow will make it seem as it is.

```
.box_wrapper{
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:0px;
}
```

Our HTML gains a wrapper :

```
  <div class="box_wrapper">
      <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

And the result is something of a responsive workaround!

[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/xs5emvd1/1)

If you update the `.box_wrapper` size in the fiddle, the bordered box will look like it's adjusting its width.

***Note***: There may be a much better way to achieve this!

Comment: This is not responsive which is a *requirement*

Comment: I agree - sorry its not 100% width either so I can't mark it as the answer. Sorry.

Comment: You're right, updating now!

Comment: @Paulie_D I also agree that this is a possible duplicate of the one given! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ukuser32 updated : Not the prettiest method, but it's something of a workaround!